# Differences between Worker Applications and Tasks in Pivotal Cloud Foundry and invoking a linux application

Tags: linux, cloud-foundry

I have a third party linux application which must run and finish before the main Spring Boot application runs. I have read about worker applications and one-off tasks, but currently I don't know in which category my use case falls. The linux application is somehow dependent on the main application so I think a one off task (with run-task) is what I need.

At the same time, the linux application must finish before the main application is started. If my assumption is correct, I would be glad to know how I can be certain the linux application has finished before starting the main application.
On the other hand, I would like to know how I can push the linux application on Cloud Foundry in case I need to treat it as a worker application.

Answer (score 0):

A worker is a way to run multiple OS processes based off of the same code base. For example, if you have a web application and in addition to the web part it has a background process, which perhaps processes long running jobs or something like that. Both the web and worker process would be designed to run at the same time and run forever (i.e. never exit, if it exits that's a crash).

A task while based on the same code branch is not designed to run in parallel with your main app. It will run for a period of time and exit. The classic example is for batch processing and single run jobs, like if you have a set of records that need to be processed, when those are complete the task then exits (this is expected and is not a crash). Tasks are often used in conjunction with a scheduler and run again and again.

Neither one is a perfect match for what you are trying to do. You could use a task, but you would need to manually manage the task and get it to run prior to your app starting. You could do that with a shell script and the cf cli, for example: push your app with `--no-start`, run your task, wait for it to finish, then `cf start` your app.

A couple other things you could do:

- [Package a `.profile` script with your app](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/deploy-app.html#profile). This will get executed in the same container as your app but prior to your app running. The app won't start unless the script completes successfully. That's pretty much what you said you want, but it has a severe limitation in that you only have a small amount of time for your `.profile` script to finish (default 60s, max 180s on most platforms, it's basically `cf push -t`). If it doesn't finish fast enough your app will be considered to have not started, and it will be restarted. This will also run every time your app starts and in every app instance, which may not be what you want. Last thing on this, the docs say you can't use this with a Java app but they are wrong, it's just more complicated).
- Modify your start command (i.e. `cf push -c`). This is basically the same as `.profile` except that you put multiple commands into the start command, like `cf push -c 'do_something_1 && do_something_2 && do_something_3 ...'`). This option has similar limitations to the `.profile` option, plus it doesn't work well with the Java buildpack which has a fairly long and complicated start command (don't use this option for Java apps).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Really well differentiated, thanks. I never knew a Worker Application is a long  also a LRP and runs in the realm of another App. In that case a Worker does not apply in my use case. I followed the "one-off task" direction actually but I am stuck at another requirement.

Comment: My current understanding of a one-off task is that, it is called after pushing the main application, so it is also related to a primary app, since I have to quote the name of the main app before running the task. How can I access the local file system to tell the command where to find my binary and other associated files? Can I treat the Task as standalone app, i.e push like a normal app?

Comment: `My current understanding of a one-off task is that, it is called after pushing the main application` -> That's not correct. When you push the app, that just uploads the code & will start the app unless you add the `--no-start` flag. It does not run any tasks. If you need/want to run a task, you need to manually run the task.

Comment: `it is also related to a primary app, since I have to quote the name of the main app before running the task` -> Correct, the two are related. They share the same code base. When run, the app will have its own container and the task will have its own container. There is no overlap except the same code base & installed dependencies (like Java).

Comment: `How can I access the local file system to tell the command where to find my binary and other associated files?` -> Just like you would in an app. You have an ephemeral local file system that contains your app source code & dependencies (like Java). This is the exact same thing exposed to your app, just a unique copy since the task & app are in separate containers. The lifetime of the local file system is the same as the lifetime of the task.

Comment: `Can I treat the Task as standalone app, i.e push like a normal app?` -> Kind of. An app must run forever. If you pushed your task as an app, it ran and exited like a task would normally do, the platform would treat that as a crash because you told the platform that it's an app and apps, unlike tasks, run forever. You'd need some sort of signal to know when the task is done & then you'd need to stop/delete the app-task otherwise the platform would keep restarting it and your app-task might run multiple times.

Comment: Hi Daniei, I am understanding this stuff, your highlights are really vivid. I will put the gained knowledge into practice and give feedback. Thanks